# Link with custom text with K.O

Tags: knockout.js, hyperlink

This is a super easy question, I know- But I cant figure it out!
How can I create a link with custom text?

I want it to say "Est. (and the order number) " as a link.

```
 <tr>
        <td class = "hiddenId"><span data-bind="text: estimateBookId"/></td>
        **<td><a data-bind="text: orderNumber, attr: { href: '/WrenchScienceWebAdmin/OrderManager/WorkOrderTemp.aspx?orderid=' + 'Est.' + 'orderNumber' }" target="_new"></a></td>**
        <td><span data-bind="text: createDate" /></td>
        <td><a data-bind="text: customerName, attr: { href: '/WrenchScienceWebAdmin/UserManager/Customer/CustomerEditor.aspx?CustomerID=' + 'customerName'}" target="_new"></a></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: customerFirstName" /></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: customerLastName" /></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: salesPerson" /></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Notes" /></td>
   </tr>
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are sections of your code that, if shared, would help in answering your question with a solution more catered to how you are using Knockout.

Anyway, a short answer in code is below:

```
<a data-bind="text: 'Est.' + orderNumber(), attr: { href: '/WrenchScienceWebAdmin/OrderManager/WorkOrderTemp.aspx?orderid=' + orderNumber() }" target="_new"></a>
```

A longer answer in code, along with a working sample, is available here on jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/xapibicusa/1/edit?html,js,output

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">

      <h4>sample table</h4>

      <table class="table table-condensed">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>EstBookId</th>
             <th>Work Order</th>
             <th>cust. Editor</th>
             <th>cust. FirstName</th>
             <th>cust. LastName</th>
             <th>salesPerson</th>
             <th>Notes</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>  <!-- ko foreach: my.VM.CustomerOrders -->
           <tr>
             <td><span data-bind="text: estimateBookId"></span></td>
             <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: WorkOrderLink }, text: WorkOrderLinkText" target="_blank"></a></td>
             <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: CustomerEditorLink }, text: CustomerEditorLinkText" target="_blank"></a></td>
             <td><span data-bind="text: customerFirstName"></span></td>
             <td><span data-bind="text: customerLastName"></span></td>
             <td><span data-bind="text: salesPerson"></span></td>
             <td><span data-bind="text: Notes"></span></td>
          </tr>  <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var initialData = [
  { orderNumber: 1, estimateBookId: 1000, customerId: 77, customerFirstName: "John", customerLastName: "Smith", salesPerson: "Danny Boy", Notes: "well done" },
  { orderNumber: 2, estimateBookId: 1001, customerId: 78, customerFirstName: "Billy", customerLastName: "Bones", salesPerson: "Fritz Tomato", Notes: "come on!" },
  { orderNumber: 3, estimateBookId: 1002, customerId: 79, customerFirstName: "Mary", customerLastName: "Anderson", salesPerson: "Jeff Jefferson", Notes: "get going" },
  { orderNumber: 4, estimateBookId: 1003, customerId: 80, customerFirstName: "Donald", customerLastName: "Duck", salesPerson: "Danny Boy", Notes: "do something" },
  { orderNumber: 5, estimateBookId: 1004, customerId: 81, customerFirstName: "Tommy", customerLastName: "John", salesPerson: "Danny Boy", Notes: "go, go, go!" }
];


var my = my || {};

my.CustomerOrder = function () {
  var self = this; 
  self.orderNumber = ko.observable();
  self.estimateBookId = ko.observable();
  self.customerId = ko.observable();
  self.customerFirstName = ko.observable();
  self.customerLastName = ko.observable();
  self.salesPerson = ko.observable();
  self.Notes = ko.observable();  
  self.WorkOrderLink = ko.computed(function () {
     return '/WrenchScienceWebAdmin/OrderManager/WorkOrderTemp.aspx?orderid=' + self.orderNumber();
  });
  self.WorkOrderLinkText = ko.computed(function () {
    return 'Est. ' + self.orderNumber();
  });
  self.CustomerEditorLink = ko.computed(function () {
    return  '/WrenchScienceWebAdmin/UserManager/Customer/CustomerEditor.aspx?CustomerID=' + self.customerId();
  });
  self.CustomerEditorLinkText = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.customerFirstName() + ' ' + self.customerLastName();
  });
};

my.VM = function () {
  var CustomerOrders = ko.observableArray([]),
      load_initialData = function( _initialData ) {
        // clear array if loading dynamic data
        CustomerOrders([]);

        $.each( _initialData, function( i, d ) {
          CustomerOrders.push( new my.CustomerOrder()
            .orderNumber(d.orderNumber)
            .estimateBookId(d.estimateBookId)
            .customerId(d.customerId)
            .customerFirstName(d.customerFirstName)
            .customerLastName(d.customerLastName)
            .salesPerson(d.salesPerson)
            .Notes(d.Notes)
          );
        });

      };
  return {
    load_initialData: load_initialData,
    CustomerOrders: CustomerOrders
  };
}();

$(function() {
  my.VM.load_initialData( initialData );
  ko.applyBindings( my.VM );
});
```

The code sample uses the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) 
as inspired by one of John Papa's KnockoutJS courses for Pluralsight.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotes around the name of the model property you're using in the expression, since that's just treated as literal text. Do put parens after the name, since in an expression you have to treat a model property as a function to get its value:

```
attr: { href: '/WrenchScienceWebAdmin/OrderManager/WorkOrderTemp.aspx?orderid=' + 'Est.' + orderNumber()}
```